# C++ C# Projects dependency management

Tags: c#, .net, c++, project-management, dependency-management

I'm trying to figure out how to manage our main Visual Studio solution.
In the solution we have to manage C++/CLI projects, C++ native projects, C# projects, external dependencies (compiled C# assemblies with their own dependencies) managed by other teams and frequently updated (together with their dependencies).

Every type of project can be a dependency for each other (except C# or C++ native of course).
Some C# projects have dependencies on external DLLs which can require some other DLLs to work properly.

Until now we have used post-build-steps to copy references to each project's output directory (additional dependencies for C# libraries compiled externally and required C++ DLLs).
We would like to automate this process. Projects are many, and external DLLs are often managed by other teams (sometimes they add more and more dependencies) and we would like every change made by them to be automatically reflected on our main project.
Is there a tool, a best practice for batch files, or something not to lose ourselves in this dependency hell and just make a svn update and a little configuration effort every time a new project is included in a solution?

One of my problems is if I have a C# project1.dll which requires C# project1a.dll and C# project 1b.dll, if my C# project2 requires project1.dll I would prefer not to add project1a.dll and project1b.dll to project2 references but I would like to find it in my output folder (this is because project1a is managed by another team and day by day could require project1x.dll to work).

How did you solve this requirement?

Comment: There is an option in VS to automatically link project dependencies. I manage quite large projects with several C++ static libs depending on a bunch of libraries (boost, BLAS, etc), C++/CLI DLLS and C# projects (shared add ins, standalone console programs, windows forms programs) and I never ran into any problems with dependency management. The only thing is to specify external libs to the linker for the (distributed) DLLs, not for the static libs. I use VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Microsoft Connect [suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514169/2010-beta-2-others-expanding-solution-project-build-settings-to-include-refernces) requesting simular features, (this one's mine actually).  Unfortunatly references do not update with your solution build configurations very well.  It forces you to split up your project and maintain redundant project/solutions in some cases (like binary references).

If you can build all of your project from *source* then you have nothing to worry about, but this is rare, and you can see in the connect suggestion, it's not possiable for some system dependencies.

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) for some heavy duty for build customization.

Comment: Unfortunately first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NuGet and hosting your own [package feed](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hosting%20Your%20Own%20Local%20and%20Remote%20NuPack%20Feeds)?